# How to solve android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException in Android 11?

Tags: java, kotlin, cryptography, android-security, android-jetpack-security

I am getting to many of below android security related exception/crash on my test enviourment

Device: Galaxy A52 5G
Android: 11

**Updated stack traces**

```
ndroid.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException KeyStore.java:1441
android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException KeyStore.java:1548
android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getInvalidKeyExceptionForInit KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:54
android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getExceptionForCipherInit KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:89
android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.ensureKeystoreOperationInitialized AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:265
android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineInit AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:109
javax.crypto.Cipher.tryTransformWithProvider Cipher.java:2984
javax.crypto.Cipher.tryCombinations Cipher.java:2891
javax.crypto.Cipher$SpiAndProviderUpdater.updateAndGetSpiAndProvider Cipher.java:2796
javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider Cipher.java:773
javax.crypto.Cipher.init Cipher.java:1143
javax.crypto.Cipher.init Cipher.java:1084
au.com.gridstone.pscore.hkpf.data.providers.PushNotificationAlertEncryptionProvider.decrypt PushNotificationAlertEncryptionProvider.java:17
au.******package******.providers.PushNotificationAlertEncryptionProvider.decrypt PushNotificationAlertEncryptionProvider.java
au.c******package******.background.messaging.FirebaseCloudMessagingService.processMessage FirebaseCloudMessagingService.java:153
au.******package******.background.messaging.FirebaseCloudMessagingService.access$processMessage FirebaseCloudMessagingService.java
au.******package******.hkpf.background.messaging.FirebaseCloudMessagingService$onMessageReceived$1.invokeSuspend FirebaseCloudMessagingService.java:32
kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith BaseContinuationImpl.java:9
kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run DispatchedTask.java:129
kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely CoroutineScheduler.java:1
kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask CoroutineScheduler.java:14
kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker CoroutineScheduler.java:28
kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run CoroutineScheduler.java
```

**Backgorund**
In my project we are using RSA to send Push notification from Firbase to devices, server uses client public key to encrypt the notification data and client uses its private key to decrypt the notification after receiving it before displaying to users.

**Code**

```
fun retrieveKey(keyAlias: String): KeyPair? {
 val keyStore: KeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore")
    keyStore.load(null)

    val privateKey: PrivateKey? = keyStore.getKey(keyAlias, null) as? PrivateKey
    val publicKey: PublicKey? = keyStore.getCertificate(keyAlias)?.publicKey

    // If key is already found, return it
    if (privateKey != null && publicKey != null) {
      return KeyPair(publicKey, privateKey)
    }

    // Even if a key is not found, any records of a key alias must be purged
    keyStore.deleteEntry(keyAlias)

    // Generate it with keystore set to the provider, so that the provider takes care of storing it
    val generator: KeyPairGenerator =
        KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, "AndroidKeyStore")

    val keySpec: KeyGenParameterSpec = KeyGenParameterSpec
        .Builder(keyAlias, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
        .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_ECB)
        .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
        .setKeySize(1024)
        .build()

    generator.initialize(keySpec)


    val keyPair: KeyPair? = try {
      generator.generateKeyPair()
    } catch (exception: Throwable) {
      Crashes.trackError(exception)
      null
    }

    return keyPair
  }
```

**usage**
To register a user device and sending a public key to server

```
fun register(pushToken: String, userCredentials: UserCredentials): Result<Unit> {
    
    val keyPair: KeyPair? = keyProvider.retrieveKey(PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS_KEY_ALIAS)

    val publicKeySpecFromEncoded: X509EncodedKeySpec? =
      keyPair?.public?.encoded?.let { X509EncodedKeySpec(it) }

    val pushKey: String? =
      publicKeySpecFromEncoded?.encoded?.let { String(Base64.encode(it, Base64.DEFAULT)) }

    val encryptionInstructions: EncryptionInstructions? =
      pushKey?.let { EncryptionInstructions(key = it) }

    val registration = DeviceRegistration(
      pushKey = pushKey.orEmpty(),
      pushToken = pushToken,
      encryptionInstructions = encryptionInstructions,
      deviceUuid = userCredentials.deviceUuid
    )

    return authWebServices.registerDevice(registration)
  }
```

And here is the code for function to decrypt the notification

```
decrypt(data: String, privateKey: Key?): PushNotificationData? {
    val cipher: Cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ENCRYPTION_CIPHER)
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey)

    val encrypted: ByteArray = Base64.decode(data, Base64.DEFAULT)

    // This should only deal with RSA keys
    if (privateKey !is RSAKey) return null

    // Block size will limit how much we can decrypt at once, and specific to cipher
    val blockSize: Int = DECRYPTION_BLOCK_SIZE
    val chunks: List<ByteArray> = encrypted.chunked(blockSize)

    // Catch any errors when decrypting
    val decrypted: ByteArray = try {
      chunks.fold(ByteArray(encrypted.size)) { acc, byteArray ->
        acc + cipher.doFinal(byteArray)
      }
    } catch (t: Throwable) {
      Crashes.trackError(t)
      return null
    }
......
......
return pushNotificationData
}
```

I had tried puting this in try catch but it will silently fail the notification to crash.
the app is working properly on android 12 and above.

Comment: Your stacktrace is trimmed to exclude some of the most important pieces of information: the actual exceptions that're thrown and the description strings. It should include the final exception and any re-thrown exceptions, particularly the original exception.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk thanks I had updated the stack traces the app is in production and still getting this expections thanks for the reply

Comment: There are no exception messages.  Post the complete stacktrace without redacting, editing, or otherwise mangling it.

Comment: I notice that you are using Microsoft App Center "Crashes".  I'm not familiar with that.  I guess it *might* be serving you up mangled stacktraces?  If that is what is going on ... maybe you need to resort to directly capturing the output of `t.printStackTrace()` or something.

Comment: @StephenC correct I am using app center but is not reproducible on the same devices which is strange also the app is running perfectly without any interruption, but our app center Diagnostics keep piling up with such error

Comment: I'm merely talking about the mangled stacktraces.  Please post **complete unmangled** stacktraces.  If you don't, I doubt that people will be able to figure out what is going on.  I'm certainly not going to use time trying to work with incomplete information.  If your security practices won't let you post complete stacktraces, perhaps you need to hire a consultant and get them to sign an NDA so that they can help you.

Comment: @StephenC this is the complete stack traces form the app centre i wish i could have more over there to share but unfortunately we don't have more to share :(